# I am making a calculator and this is returning null in all the cases

Tags: django

This is views.py and the value of c is getting displayed on the browser as null. num1 is the name of my first html textbox. Num2 is the name of my Second html textbox

```
 def calc(request):
        a=int(request.POST["num1"])
        b=int(request.POST["num2"])
        if 'add' in request.POST:    
            c=a+b
            return c
        if 'sub' in request.POST:    
            c=a-b
            return c   
        if 'mul' in request.POST:    
            c=a*b
            return c
        if 'div' in request.POST:    
            c=a/b
            return c
    
    def calprint(request):
        c=calc(request)
        return render(request,"result.html",{"result":c})
```

this is the HTML where the method is post

```
 <form action="calc" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
       num 1 <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
       num 2 <input type="text" name="num2"><br>
       <input type="submit" value="add">
       <input type="submit" value="sub">
       <input type="submit" value="mul">
       <input type="submit" value="div">
    </form>
```

This is the urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('calc',views.calprint,name='add')
]
```

Comment: you dont have `add` `sub` and other operations in `request.POST` as `key`, you can print it and see. that is why you don't choose any operation and your function return None. add names to your submit buttons

Comment: actually today is my first day in django and i did not understant what you said.can you please help me with the code

Answer (score 2):

in your code

```
if 'add' in request.POST:    
            c=a+b
            return c
```

you check that request.POST have an item with key == 'add'
but in your html form you don't provide names for your operation submits. make this changes to your html

```
   <input type="submit" name="add" value="add">
   <input type="submit" name="sub" value="sub">
   <input type="submit" name="mul" value="mul">
   <input type="submit" name="div" value="div">
```